# Database appears empty upon re-entry into activity

Tags: android, android-database

Anyone know why my database is not saving as expected? When I am in my Activity, I can save and load data from the database easy enough. As soon as i leave and renter the database activity, it does not retain any information of the database.

I am using a database helper

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
```

In order to generate initial tables i do this at the intro, make a writable database request to initiate a onCreate(). When i left this out, the system would error because no database existed.

```
public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    myDataBase.close();
}
```

I generate tables onCreate

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DAILYWORK (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "day INTEGER," +
            "time TEXT," +
            "work INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DAILYPREACHLOG (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "day INTEGER," +
            "time TEXT," +
            "contacts INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "m20 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "m30 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "m40 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "f20 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "f30 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "f40 INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONTACTLOG (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "firstname TEXT," +
            "lastname TEXT," +
            "phone TEXT," +
            "email TEXT," +
            "address TEXT)");
}
```

from what i read generating onCreate() with the sqlhelper implemented will only create the tables if they do not exist. It seems however, that every time i enter it erases old tables and recreates them fresh.

Full database activity per request

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
private static final String DATABASE_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.johnbravado.zionwork/databases/";
private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "zionWorkDB.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase = null;

private final Context myContext;

public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    this.myContext = context;
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    myDataBase.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DAILYWORK (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "day INTEGER," +
            "time TEXT," +
            "work INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DAILYPREACHLOG (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "day INTEGER," +
            "time TEXT," +
            "contacts INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "m20 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "m30 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "m40 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "f20 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "f30 INTEGER DEFAULT 0," +
            "f40 INTEGER DEFAULT 0)");

    db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE CONTACTLOG (" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," +
            "firstname TEXT," +
            "lastname TEXT," +
            "phone TEXT," +
            "email TEXT," +
            "address TEXT)");
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase arg0, int arg1, int arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    // Drop older table if existed
    //arg0.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NEWSONGS);
    // Create tables again
    onCreate(arg0);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close() {

    if (myDataBase != null)
        myDataBase.close();

    super.close();

}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {

    //Open the database
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);

}

public boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //database does not exist yet
    }

    if (checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }

    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

public void reset() throws IOException {
    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if (dbExist) {
        myContext.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
    }

}

public void addDailyWork(long day, String time, int work) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("day", day);
    values.put("time", time);
    values.put("work", work);

    db.insert("DAILYWORK", null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void addDailyPreachLog(long day, String time, int[] counts) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put("day", day);
    values.put("time", time);
    values.put("contacts", counts[6]);
    values.put("m20", counts[0]);
    values.put("m30", counts[1]);
    values.put("m40", counts[2]);
    values.put("f20", counts[3]);
    values.put("f30", counts[4]);
    values.put("f40", counts[5]);

    db.insert("DAILYPREACHLOG", null, values);
    db.close();
}

public void updateDailyPreachLog(long day, String time, int[] counts) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    String whereClause = "day=" + String.format(String.format("%1$d", day)) + " AND time=\"" + time + "\"";

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    //values.put("day", day);
    //values.put("time", time);
    values.put("contacts", counts[6]);
    values.put("m20", counts[0]);
    values.put("m30", counts[1]);
    values.put("m40", counts[2]);
    values.put("f20", counts[3]);
    values.put("f30", counts[4]);
    values.put("f40", counts[5]);

    db.update("DAILYPREACHLOG", values, whereClause, null);
    db.close();
}

public String getPreachLogString(long day, String time) {
    String selectQuery;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    String tmp;
    String result = null;
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DAILYPREACHLOG WHERE day = " + day + " AND time = \"" + time + "\"";
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        tmp = String.format("M20:%1$d : M30:%2$d : M40:%3$d : F20:%4$d : F30:%5$d : F40:%6$d",
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("m20")),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("m30")),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("m40")),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("f20")),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("f30")),
                cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("f40")));
        result = tmp;
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return result;
}

public HashMap<String, Integer> getPreachLogData(long day, String time) {
    String selectQuery;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    Cursor cursor;
    String tmp;

    HashMap<String, Integer> result = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DAILYPREACHLOG WHERE day = " + day + " AND time = \"" + time + "\"";
    cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_M20_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("m20")));
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_M30_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("m30")));
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_M40_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("m40")));
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_F20_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("f20")));
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_F30_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("f30")));
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_F40_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("f40")));
        result.put(MyConstants.DB_CONTACTS_HASH_KEY, cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("contacts")));
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return result;
}

public ArrayList<String> getMonthlyWork(int year, int month) {
    long thismonth = 0;
    long nextmonth = 0;
    String selectQuery;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    ArrayList<String> result = new ArrayList<>();
    SimpleDateFormat formatDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);

    String myPath = DATABASE_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;

    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.set(year, month, 1);

    thismonth = c.getTimeInMillis();

    if (month < 11) {
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, month + 1);
    } else {
        c.set(Calendar.MONTH, 0);
        c.set(Calendar.YEAR, year + 1);
    }
    nextmonth = c.getTimeInMillis();

    db = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM DAILYWORK WHERE day BETWEEN " + thismonth + " AND " + nextmonth;
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        c.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("day")));
        formatDate.format(c.getTime());
        result.add(formatDate.format(c.getTime()) + ", "
                + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")) + ", "
                + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("work")));
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            c.setTimeInMillis(cursor.getLong(cursor.getColumnIndex("day")));
            formatDate.format(c.getTime());
            result.add(formatDate.format(c.getTime()) + ", "
                    + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("time")) + ", "
                    + cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex("work")));
        }
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return result;
}
}
```

partial activity because too long

```
public class CounterActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements
    GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks,
    GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   //stuff removed for space
    initgui();

}

    tod_spin = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.counter_tod_spinner);
    ArrayAdapter tofdAdapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource (this, R.array.tofd, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    tofdAdapter.setDropDownViewResource (android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    tod_spin.setAdapter(tofdAdapter);
    tod_spin.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        DatabaseHandler db;
        HashMap<String, Integer> preachData;

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
            db = new DatabaseHandler(CounterActivity.this);
            preachData = db.getPreachLogData(dateInMillis, tod_spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
            db.close();
            if(pos == 0){
                save_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(false);
                view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(false);
            }else{
                save_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(true);

                if(preachData.isEmpty()){
                    view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(false);
                }else{
                    view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(true);
                }
                db.close();
            }
            updateCounterInterfaceCounts(preachData);
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {

        }
    });

    final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
    dateInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

    tv_counter_date =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.counter_date_tv);
    tv_counter_date.setText(new StringBuilder()
            .append(month + 1).append("-")
            .append(day).append("-").append(year)
            .append(" "));
    tv_counter_date.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            showDialog(MyConstants.DATE_DIALOG_ID);
        }
    });

    save_preachlog_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_save_count);
    save_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(false);
    save_preachlog_btn.setText(MyConstants.START_SERVICE_BTN_LBL);
    save_preachlog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            int[] counters = new int[7];
            String currentState = save_preachlog_btn.getText().toString();
            DatabaseHandler db;

            if(currentState.compareTo(MyConstants.START_SERVICE_BTN_LBL) == 0){

                tod_spin.setEnabled(false);
                tv_counter_date.setEnabled(false);
                view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(false);

                if(!MyWearableListenerService.isRunning()){
                    startService(wearListenerIntent);
                }
                db = new DatabaseHandler(CounterActivity.this);
                if(db.getPreachLogString(dateInMillis, tod_spin.getSelectedItem().toString()) == null){
                    save_preachlog_btn.setText(MyConstants.SAVE_SERVICE_BTN_LBL);
                }else{
                    save_preachlog_btn.setText(MyConstants.UPDATE_SERVICE_BTN_LBL);
                }
                db.close();

                enableCountButtons();

            }else if(currentState.compareTo(MyConstants.SAVE_SERVICE_BTN_LBL) == 0){
                save_preachlog_btn.setText(MyConstants.START_SERVICE_BTN_LBL);
                disableCountButtons();

                stopService(wearListenerIntent);

                counters[0] = m20CountTotal;
                counters[1] = m30CountTotal;
                counters[2] = m40CountTotal;
                counters[3] = f20CountTotal;
                counters[4] = f30CountTotal;
                counters[5] = f40CountTotal;
                counters[6] = contactCountTotal;

                db = new DatabaseHandler(CounterActivity.this);
                db.addDailyPreachLog(dateInMillis, tod_spin.getSelectedItem().toString(), counters);
                db.close();

                tod_spin.setEnabled(true);
                tv_counter_date.setEnabled(true);
                view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(true);

            }else if(currentState.compareTo(MyConstants.UPDATE_SERVICE_BTN_LBL) == 0){
                save_preachlog_btn.setText(MyConstants.START_SERVICE_BTN_LBL);
                disableCountButtons();

                stopService(wearListenerIntent);

                counters[0] = m20CountTotal;
                counters[1] = m30CountTotal;
                counters[2] = m40CountTotal;
                counters[3] = f20CountTotal;
                counters[4] = f30CountTotal;
                counters[5] = f40CountTotal;
                counters[6] = contactCountTotal;

                db = new DatabaseHandler(CounterActivity.this);
                db.updateDailyPreachLog(dateInMillis, tod_spin.getSelectedItem().toString(), counters);
                db.close();

                tod_spin.setEnabled(true);
                tv_counter_date.setEnabled(true);
                view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(true);
            }

        }
    });

    view_preachlog_btn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_view_count);
    view_preachlog_btn.setEnabled(false);
    view_preachlog_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String log;
            DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(CounterActivity.this);
            log = db.getPreachLogString(dateInMillis, tod_spin.getSelectedItem().toString());
            db.close();

            Toast.makeText(CounterActivity.this, log, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            sendNotification("Preach Log", log);
        }
    });

    disableCountButtons();
}

private void updateCounterInterfaceCounts(HashMap<String, Integer> data) {
    if(data.isEmpty()){
        m20CountTotal = 0;
        m30CountTotal = 0;
        m40CountTotal = 0;
        f20CountTotal = 0;
        f30CountTotal = 0;
        f40CountTotal = 0;
        contactCountTotal = 0;
    }else {
        m20CountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_M20_HASH_KEY);
        m30CountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_M30_HASH_KEY);
        m40CountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_M40_HASH_KEY);
        f20CountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_F20_HASH_KEY);
        f30CountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_F30_HASH_KEY);
        f40CountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_F40_HASH_KEY);
        contactCountTotal = data.get(MyConstants.DB_CONTACTS_HASH_KEY);
    }
    preachCountTotal = m20CountTotal + m30CountTotal + m40CountTotal +
            f20CountTotal + f30CountTotal + f40CountTotal;

    preachCountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", preachCountTotal));
    contactCountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", contactCountTotal));
    m20_vcb.setCount(m20CountTotal);
    m30_vcb.setCount(m30CountTotal);
    m40_vcb.setCount(m40CountTotal);
    f20_vcb.setCount(f20CountTotal);
    f30_vcb.setCount(f30CountTotal);
    f40_vcb.setCount(f40CountTotal);
}

private void disableCountButtons(){
    contactSubCountBtn.setEnabled(false);
    m20_vcb.disable();
    m30_vcb.disable();
    m40_vcb.disable();
    f20_vcb.disable();
    f30_vcb.disable();
    f40_vcb.disable();
}

private void enableCountButtons(){
    contactSubCountBtn.setEnabled(true);
    m20_vcb.enable();
    m30_vcb.enable();
    m40_vcb.enable();
    f20_vcb.enable();
    f30_vcb.enable();
    f40_vcb.enable();
    contactAddCountBtn.setEnabled(true);
}

private void sendMessageToWearable(final String path, final String text) {

    new Thread( new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            NodeApi.GetConnectedNodesResult nodes = Wearable.NodeApi.getConnectedNodes(mGoogleApiClient).await();
            for(Node node : nodes.getNodes()) {
                MessageApi.SendMessageResult result = Wearable.MessageApi.sendMessage(
                        mGoogleApiClient, node.getId(), path, text.getBytes() ).await();
            }

            runOnUiThread( new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    //mEditText.setText( "" );
                }
            });
        }
    }).start();

}

private DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener datePickerListener
        = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

    // when dialog box is closed, below method will be called.
    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int selectedYear,
                          int selectedMonth, int selectedDay) {
        year = selectedYear;
        month = selectedMonth;
        day = selectedDay;

        // set selected date into textview
        tv_counter_date.setText(new StringBuilder().append(month + 1)
                .append("-").append(day).append("-").append(year)
                .append(" "));
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance(Locale.US);
        c.set(year, month, day);

        dateInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();

    }
};

private void SendIntDataToWear(String path, String key, int data) {
    PutDataMapRequest putDataMapReq = PutDataMapRequest.create(path);
    putDataMapReq.getDataMap().putInt(key, data);
    PutDataRequest putDataReq = putDataMapReq.asPutDataRequest();
    PendingResult<DataApi.DataItemResult> pendingResult =
            Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(mGoogleApiClient, putDataReq);
}

private boolean showToast(String message){
    Toast.makeText(CounterActivity.this, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return true;
}

private void sendNotification(String title, String content){
    int notificationId = 001;
    //Building notification layout
    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder =
            new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                    .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                    .setContentTitle(title)
                    .setContentText(content)
                    .setVibrate(new long[]{1000,1000})
                    .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_ALL);

    // instance of the NotificationManager service
    NotificationManagerCompat notificationManager =
            NotificationManagerCompat.from(this);

    // Build the notification and notify it using notification manager.
    notificationManager.notify(notificationId, notificationBuilder.build());
}

private int increasePreachCountTotal(){
    preachCountTotal++;
    preachCountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", preachCountTotal));
    return preachCountTotal;
}

private int decreasePreachCountTotal(){
    if(preachCountTotal > 0){
        preachCountTotal--;
    }
    preachCountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", preachCountTotal));
    return preachCountTotal;
}



private void increaseCountTotal(int count){
    switch(count){
        case MyConstants.M20:
            m20CountTotal++;
            break;
        case MyConstants.M30:
            m30CountTotal++;
            break;
        case MyConstants.M40:
            m40CountTotal++;
            break;
        case MyConstants.F20:
            f20CountTotal++;
            break;
        case MyConstants.F30:
            f30CountTotal++;
            break;
        case MyConstants.F40:
            f40CountTotal++;
            break;
    }
    increasePreachCountTotal();
}

private void decreaseCountTotal(int count){
    switch(count){
        case MyConstants.M20:
            if(m20CountTotal > 0){
                m20CountTotal--;
                decreasePreachCountTotal();
            }
            //m20CountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", m20CountTotal));
            break;
        case MyConstants.M30:
            if(m30CountTotal > 0){
                m30CountTotal--;
                decreasePreachCountTotal();
            }
            //m30CountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", m30CountTotal));
            break;
        case MyConstants.M40:
            if(m40CountTotal > 0){
                m40CountTotal--;
                decreasePreachCountTotal();
            }
            //m40CountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", m40CountTotal));
            break;
        case MyConstants.F20:
            if(f20CountTotal > 0){
                f20CountTotal--;
                decreasePreachCountTotal();
            }
            //f20CountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", f20CountTotal));
            break;
        case MyConstants.F30:
            if(f30CountTotal > 0){
                f30CountTotal--;
                decreasePreachCountTotal();
            }
            //f30CountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", f30CountTotal));
            break;
        case MyConstants.F40:
            if(f40CountTotal > 0){
                f40CountTotal--;
                decreasePreachCountTotal();
            }
            //f40CountTotalTv.setText(String.format("%1$d", f40CountTotal));
            break;
    }

}



public class WearableReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        //Intent service = new Intent(context, WearableReceiverService.class);
        //startWakefulService(context, service);
        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
        PowerManager.WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
                "com.example.johnbravado.zionwork");
        wakeLock.acquire();
        // Do Work
        msgReqAction(intent.getIntExtra(MyConstants.BROADCAST_DATA_REQ, 0));

        wakeLock.release();
    }
}

}
```

Comment: please put full code of your activity

Comment: I posted the full database activity. did you want the full activity i used to call the database functions also?

Comment: Post the code of the activity, you have declared a reset method in the class, may be you are calling it accidentally somewhere. However you can try **Create Table TABLE_NAME if not exists**

Comment: added calling activity. had to remove stuff for space but it was just declaration and generations or had no db calls. i also tried the if not exists and it still did not restore the saved data

Comment: Ignore this I think I see my error. When I am calling time and date and sending it. Because I do not lock down a time of hours via c.setHour...And make a std time the. When I come back the Long I send to the function. Has a new second associated to it. So it is considering it a different time. I will test when I get home tonihbt if this was answered I will post as answer

Answer (score 0):

This was an unrelated error and was a result of not giving the right information to the db. because i was not setting the hour, minute and millisecond of the time variable i was using as a verification field, then the value was not being found.

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
dateInMillis = c.getTimeInMillis();
// Added this to make it work
c.set(year, month, day, 4, 0, 0);
c.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
// End addition
db = new DatabaseHandler(CounterActivity.this);
db.addDailyPreachLog(dateInMillis, tod_spin.getSelectedItem().toString(), counters);
db.close();
```